# How can I create looping inside looping on javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9HQZ.png)

```js
let pjumlah_kelulusan_perprodi = this.state.jml_lulusan_perprodi;
let result_jml_kelulusan_perprodi = [];
var i = 0;
for (var key in pjumlah_kelulusan_perprodi) {
  result_jml_kelulusan_perprodi[i] = {
name: key,
count: pjumlah_kelulusan_perprodi[key]
  };
  i++;
  console.log('data = ', result_jml_kelulusan_perprodi);
}
```

I want to loop that "count"

Comment: where did comes from `i` and `i++;` ???

Comment: so you want to count the number of objects?

Comment: sorry, i forgot add var i = 0;

Comment: @FarazShaikh 
yes, I want to display what data is in the count

Answer (score 0):

use forEach loop and count i inside function.

```js
let pArray=[{name:"sdqwe"},{name:"asdaqwe"},{name:"Zxcasd"},{name:"qweqrt"},{name:"eqtqsdsa"}];

const result = [];

pArray.forEach((p,i)=>{
  result.push({
    object: p,
    count: i
  })
})

console.log("Data =", result);
```